# Enviar informações sobre o link clicado para o servidor antes de redirecionar

Tags: jquery, ajax

Como disparar um evento AJAX, quando o usuário clicar em um link? Considerando que, o link irá redireciona-lo para outra página.

Tentei realizar o processo, no entanto, algumas vezes o evento não é disparado(acredito que não dá tempo dá função ser disparada por causa do redirecionamento).

```
<a id="clique" href="https://www.google.com">Clique Aqui</a>

<script>
$(document).on("click", "a#clique"", function(){

$.ajax({

/* .... */

});

});
</script>
```

Minha intenção com isso é gravar o clique do usuário.

Comment: Alexandre, não votei na sua pergunta, mas acho que vc tem uma reputação muito boa para fazer uma pergunta dessa qualidade. Tenta dá uma melhorada nela. Por exemplo, o que vc quer dizer com "gravar clique"?

Comment: Grato @Sam pelas considerações. Fiz a pergunta bem rapidinho, e não me atentei em dar qualidade a pergunta, espero que esteja claro agora.

Pode sim, ainda ser uma pergunta simples, ou estar em duplicata, mas estou atrás dessa resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Olá! Ou eu não entendi nada ou o que você tá questionando você mesmo já resolveu (**leia meu comentário abaixo para ficar mais claro!**)

Execute a seguir. Pelo que vejo ao abrir a janela nova, antes o browser executa a função do onclick.

```js
 
$(document).on("click", "a#clique", function(){
 console.log('teste, fazer alguma coisa! guardar informações importantes');
 alert( 'Clicked!' );
//$.ajax({ });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="clique" href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/">Clique Aqui</a>
```

Comment: Não observei sua declaração "Tentei realizar o processo, no entanto, algumas vezes o evento não é disparado(acredito que não dá tempo dá função ser disparada por causa do redirecionamento)."
Quanto a isso, acho então que o fato de você estar tentando executar em AJAX para segundo plano é que está causando a falha em algumas vezes. Note que com o Alert ele fica preso, portanto, você não tem como fazer o "salvamento do click" sem uso de AJAX para testar?

Comment: Entendo que como opção, poderia colocar e.preventDefault() no click do elemento, acionar ajax, e depois fazer um redirect com windows.location.href.. Porém não confio muito no redirecionamento por Javacript(Acredito que alguns browsers podem negar, ou perguntar ao usuário, por ser abstrato), e também por conta de que teria que aguardar o término da requisição para posterior redirecionamento pelo JS.

Comment: Não entendo outra forma de salvar o clique sem usar AJAX(no caso, encaminhar esses dados do clique, para ser salvo posteriormente no Banco de dados), para que eu possa usar esses dados(como cliques ou visualizações).

Acredito que eu teria que, na página de destino, criar algumas regras e contabilizar esse clique.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295354/send-information-about-clicked-link-to-the-server-before-redirect?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: E se você passar por uma função que carregará o endereço em questão? vaiparaosite('https://google.com.br"); 
Não seria mais claro, prático e "quase" infalivel? / Só não pode ficar sem JS ativo :/

Answer (score 1):

Você pode modificar o href na hora do click e interceptar a URL em um arquivo PHP:

```js
$(document).on("click", "a#clique", function(){
 $(this).attr('href', 'click_register.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('href')));
 console.log( $(this).attr('href') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="clique" href="https://www.google.com">Clique Aqui</a>
```

e o **click_register.php** seria algo assim:

```
<?php
    // salvar o click vindo na $_GET['url']
    // cuidando para não emitir nenhum retorno
    // em seguida redirecionar para a URL original 
    header("Location: " . $_GET['url']);
```